# Updating scope on form submit

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a form that upon submit will POST a message to our REST API.

If successful, the REST API will return the updated value in the same JSON format as the GET call makes.

For some reason, even after the POST call has finished, the `{{escalation.policy}}` is still not updated in the scope.

```
var escalation = Escalation.save({
    policy: $scope.policy,
}).$promise.then(function (data) {
    $scope.escalation.push(data);
    alert(data);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your REST request coming in then function? Try to put error function next to then() and make sure your request is successfully executed and responded back.

Answer (score 0):

This is the current full segment of code for the submit()

```
$scope.submit = function () {

    var Escalation = $resource('/api/escalation');

    var escalation = Escalation.save({
        policy: $scope.policy,
    }).$promise.then(function (data) {
        $scope.escalation.push(data);
    }, function (error) {
        alert('This request could not be processed. Please try again later.');
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

The API will always return in the following format for a GET or POST:

```
{"policy":"Whatever the current/new policy is."}
```

Alas, i can still not seam to figure out why the view will not update.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `$scope.$apply()` after `$scope.escalation.push(data);`. That will cause a new $digest to occur forcing the view to update, my guess is that `$promise.then` is ocurring outside the usual digest loop.